# How to implement ManyToManyField as Checkboxes using django-mptt Structure in Admin?

Tags: python, django, admin, mptt

this is my code above.

#### model.py

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Descrição")
    slug = models.SlugField()

class Categoria(MPTTModel):
    produto = models.ManyToManyField(Produto, null=True, blank=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children',verbose_name="Categoria Pai")
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    ativo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    mostra_menu = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ordem_menu = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

#### admin.py

```
class CategoriaProdutoInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Categoria.produto.through

class ProdutoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('__unicode__','sku','descricao_curta', 'preco', 'preco_desconto', 'ativo', 'categorias', 'link')
    inlines = [CategoriaProdutoInline, ImagemInLine, TagInLine]
    search_fields = ('nome', 'sku', 'categoria__nome')
    list_filter = ('preco', 'created_at')
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ('nome',)}
    readonly_fields = ['link']
    fields = ('usuario','nome','descricao','ativo','preco','preco_desconto','slug')
```

Actually, the product update admin looks like this.

[Insert Product Admin Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfWjv.png)

I´ve tried to use some implementations like TreeNodeChoiceField as seem [here](http://www.abidibo.net/blog/2012/11/29/using-django-mptt-treenodechoicefield-tabularinline-admin-form/) but not works